Source to learn nowadays halacha
I am a Balat Teshua amd would love to learn halacha systematically to be able to observe mitsvas without any doubt. I have attempted to learn Shulhan Aruch by myself, but I came across some halachas which are not customary observed today. So, reading plain Shulhan Aruch will not be a help.
Do you have any suggestions? Is there any book or complete lecture series that I as a Sepharadic woman can read? TY

"learn halacha systematically to be able to observe mitsvas without any doubt" This is a never-ending project that no one book can do for you. If someone below says you can achieve it without much toil, don't believe them (Megillah 6b)

Please find a Rabbi to discuss this question with, we are unlikely to be able to help you and our attempts to do so could make things more difficult for you

I think this should be closed as Opinion Based

@DoubleAA The objective criteria are a book or complete lecture series appropriate for a Sepharadic woman etc., no different than any other [tag:product-recommendation]

@ba appropriate for a sefardic women is hardly objective

Agreed. If anything @DoubleAA's comment is an understatement. If not opinion based, should be closed on lack of detail/clarity

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch Yalkut Yosef. You can also find it online here. As the title suggests, it is a 2 volume compendium of the halachot of HaRav Ovadya Yosef.
I haven't learned the whole thing, but the parts I've learned have all been practical.

Is it come in English? Do you possibly have a link?

Also whats the diff between this version of Shulhan Aruch and Orach Chaim one?

@Angie I haven’t seen it in English, but that doesn’t mean there isn’t an English version.

I would recommend Rav Melamed's more contemporary halachic work  Peninei Halacha.  Original is in Hebrew, but there is a partial English translation.  It is available in hard copy, and on line  https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/   They also have a daily email from the Yeshiva with "halacha of the day" (as do some others) which is a good way to learn topics as presented.

I haven't heard about this Rabbi, I will look into his website belineder, ty

The בן איש חי is considered the more modern authoritative text for הלכה for Sephardiim.
Chacham Yosef Chaim (Ben Ish Chai)

Chacham Yosef Chaim authored many works, both of halakhah and agadah
(sections of the Talmud that deals with esoteric, non-legal subjects).
His most famous book is Ben Ish Chai, a book based upon the weekly
portion of the Torah with a discussion of the portion and practical
halakhah.
This book is considered the standard reference in all religious Sephardi homes and is studied by Jews worldwide. Due to the popularity
of this book, Rav Yosef Chaim came to be known by it’s name and today
he is referred to universally as the Ben Ish Chai.

בן איש חי is readily available in English, Hebrew and other languages. Chacham Yosef Chaim wrote many works dealing with numerous subjects, all now bearing the title ...בן איש חי. But AFAIK you need the book entitled simply בן איש חי. I would suggest asking some friends who are Sephardiim to point you in the right direction.

Thank you for your time

Yalkut Yosef might be a good choice. They have it in english also https://www.eichlers.com/ilqvt-ivsp-yalkut-yosef-h-e-set-18-volume-bke-yys18.html
Or as Vector wrote, Ben Ish Chai.
They do argue though, so it would seem like a good idea to ask a Rabbi which one is closer to your heritage. (or an answer to your original question)

Your last paragraph is one of the main reasons I made my comment. I have personally experienced huge issues because of things like that, and seen many others with the same.

B"H
You can learn the Kitzur shulchan aruch which contains a summarized version of the practical laws one should keep.

Not the downvoter, but I would not recommend Kitzur SA to a Sephardiya…

They have sephardic versions: https://www.mekorjudaica.com/product/kitzur-shulchan-aruch-sephardic/

@shmosel (not the downvoter either) they do (and it might be a great option) but it is a different book - not what the OP recommended
